# How to send variables from X-DATA to the server. Alpine JS & HTMX & Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, alpine.js, htmx

I have got the next snippet. There are a few **select** blocks. What I would like to do is to collect both variables and send to the Django server. But the **request.GET** is empty. What is wrong?

```
<div class="flex" x-data="{ foo: '',  bar: ''}">
  <div class="flex justify-between">
    <div class="mt-1">

      <select x-model="foo"
              name="foo"
              id="foo"
              class="w-64 h-14 text-sm border-gray-300 focus:bg-transparent">
        <option value="">Type of FOO</option>
        <option value="FOO_1">FOO_1</option>
        <option value="FOO_2">FOO_2</option>
        <option value="FOO_1">FOO_3</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-1">
      <select name="bar"
              x-model="bar"
              id="bar"
              class="w-64 h-14 text-sm border-gray-300 focus:bg-transparent">
        <option value="">BAR Types</option>
        <option value="BAR_1">BAR_1</option>
        <option value="BAR_2">BAR_2</option>
        <option value="BAR_3">BAR_3</option>
      </select>
    </div>


    <input type="text" name="foo" x-model="foo" hidden />
    <input type="text" name="bar" x-model="bar" hidden />

    <button
      hx-get="{% url 'server:parse-values' %}"
      hx-target="#element"
      hx-swap="innerHTML"
      hx-include="[name='foo', name='bar']">
    <span
      class="cursor-pointer px-3 py-3 border-2">Parse details</span>
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

But when I click on the button the Django backend does not receive **foo** and **bar** parameters.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include multiple inputs you need to separate them with a comma like this:

```
hx-include="input[name='foo'], input[name='bar']"
```

That would be the equivalent of using querySelectorAll to grab your inputs:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name='foo'], input[name='bar']")
```

I added the additional `input` so it excludes the select lists, but you can probable remove the hidden inputs from your example and just include the lists.

I should also add that if you move the htmx attributes from the button to the x-data div and change that into a form. Then change the button to type `submit`. All the form data will be automatically sent to the server.

```
<form class="flex" x-data="{ foo: '',  bar: ''}" 
        hx-get="{% url 'server:parse-values' %}"
        hx-target="#element"
        hx-swap="innerHTML"
    >
        <div class="flex justify-between">
            <div class="mt-1">

            <select x-model="foo"
                    name="foo"
                    id="foo"
                    class="w-64 h-14 text-sm border-gray-300 focus:bg-transparent">
                <option value="">Type of FOO</option>
                <option value="FOO_1">FOO_1</option>
                <option value="FOO_2">FOO_2</option>
                <option value="FOO_1">FOO_3</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="mt-1">
            <select name="bar"
                    x-model="bar"
                    id="bar"
                    class="w-64 h-14 text-sm border-gray-300 focus:bg-transparent">
                <option value="">BAR Types</option>
                <option value="BAR_1">BAR_1</option>
                <option value="BAR_2">BAR_2</option>
                <option value="BAR_3">BAR_3</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">
            <span class="cursor-pointer px-3 py-3 border-2">Parse details</span>
        </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it didn't help me. It seems that **foo** and **bar** are not sent to the server at all.

Comment: I tested the code and it works on my end. What is the payload that you see in the request made to the server?

Comment: You can see that it works in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bhnf4wxr/ 

Open browser dev tools to inspect the request and you can see the parameters are included https://www.screencast.com/t/DfuCnAhmCwZ

Comment: thank you so much! You are an incredible man! Finally I have found where a mistake was.

Comment: Glad to help. So where was the mistake?

Comment: I used a wrong template. So I changed one but the other was displayed.  :) My fault